# Unique doesn't use keys as default anymore

Tags: r, data.table, unique

I mainly use Rstudio in Mac. Recently I had to start using Windows. However, I found out that unique() does not provide unique rows in data.table based on the key. Here is an example:

```
a=c(2,3,3,3,3,5,6,7)
b=c("a","a","f","g","a","d","t","l")
e=data.table(a,b)
setkey(e, a)
key(e) # this works fine
unique(e)
```

unique() only removes the duplicate for the entire line (line 5). The exact same code runs fine on my mac.

Comment: That's because you have different data.table versions on both. On Mac you have a <1.9.8 version, while on Windows you have a newer version. Please, please, read the docs of `?unique`, e.g. "*By default all columns are being used. This was changed recently for consistency to data.frame methods. In version < 1.9.8 default was key(x)*". Then try `unique(e, by = "a")` on your Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have different data.table versions on both. On Mac you have a <1.9.8 version (which still uses keys as default), while on Windows you have a newer version (which doesn't).

As stated in `?unique` (in data.table V1.9.8+):

> By default all columns are being used. This was changed recently for
>   consistency to data.frame methods. In version < 1.9.8 default was
>   key(x)

Meaning, from now on, you need to explicitly specify the `by` variable even if you already have keys set, otherwise it will just use all the columns.

For your specific example, this works

```
unique(e, by = "a")
#    a b
# 1: 2 a
# 2: 3 a
# 3: 5 d
# 4: 6 t
# 5: 7 l
```

Or as @Frank mentioned in comments, you can also specify the the  key in the `by` param using `unique(a, by = key(a))`.

Comment: Yes exactly. The change was also to make `by=key()` explicitly needed so readers of the code later are reminded that that is happening.  Before, you had to know and if a key was added upstream it would change behaviour of `unique`.  Should be more robust now.